# VBScript, MSXML and Namespaces

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript, namespaces, msxml

Given the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetMsisdnResponse xmlns="http://my.domain.com/">
            <GetMsisdnResult>
                <RedirectUrl>http://my.domain.com/cw/DoIdentification.do2?sessionid=71de6551fc13e6625194</RedirectUrl>
            </GetMsisdnResult>
        </GetMsisdnResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am trying to access the RedirectUrl element using XPath in VBScript:

```
set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xml.async = false
xml.validateOnParse = false
xml.resolveExternals = false
xml.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xml.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:s='http://my.domain.com/' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'"

err.clear
on error resume next
xml.loadXML (xmlhttp.responseText)
if (err.number = 0) then

    redirectUrl = xml.selectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/s:GetMsisdnResponse/s:GetMsisdnResult/s:RedirectUrl").text
end if
```

but it is failing to find the RedirectUrl node, therefore is nothing when I try to get the .text property.  What am I doing wrong

Comment: @Xetius, since you are using xmlhttp why not retrieve the xmlhttp ReceivedXML property which returns a DOMDocument? (The server needs to specify an xml mime type such as text/xml in the Content-Type header).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the wrong namespace declaration.

In your XML you have

```
http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope
```

but in your Script, you use

```
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
```

This works for me:

```vb
xml.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:s='http://my.domain.com/' xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'"

' ...

Set redirectUrl = xml.selectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/s:GetMsisdnResponse/s:GetMsisdnResult/s:RedirectUrl")
```

---

On a different note - I'd try to keep the lines that are affected by an `On Error Resume Next` statement at an *absolute* minimum. Ideally, it is in effect for a single critical line only (or you wrap the critical section in a `Sub`). This makes debugging *a lot* easier.

For example, you are missing a `Set` statement in `Set redirectUrl = ...`. This will fail silently when On `Error Resume Next` is on.

Try

```vb
' this is better than loadXML(xmlHttp.responseText)
xmlDocument.load(xmlHttp.responseStream)

If (xmlDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0) Then
  ' react to the parsing error
End If

Xpath = "/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/s:GetMsisdnResponse/s:GetMsisdnResult/s:RedirectUrl"
Set redirectUrl = xml.selectSingleNode(Xpath)

If redirectUrl Is Nothing Then
  ' nothing found
Else
  ' do something
End If
```

See - no `On Error Resume Next` necessary.

Comment: Just the job - Thanks.  Have tidied up the rest of the code too.

Answer (score 3):

Also note that the namespace is case-sensitive, but that at least some MSXML force it to lower case.

So if you declare `xml.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:SSS='http://my.domain.com/'"`

and try `xml.selectSingleNode("/SSS:Envelope")` it may fail.

You would need to use `xml.selectSingleNode("/sss:Envelope")`.

Or better to make your namespaces lower case.