# VBA parse XML api URL

Tags: excel, xml, vba, api

I am trying to parse an api URL using VBA. However, cannot figure out why I get no output with the below code. No error message either. If I use another XML file it seems to work, however..

Any tips from someone of code improvement? THanks!

```vb
Sub testing()
 
   Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, post As Object

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.researchonline.se/api/MacroAdmin/GetForecast?name=policy&start=Mon%20Sep%2014%202020&end=Tue%20Sep%2014%202021", False
        .send
        Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        xmlDoc.loadXML .responseXML.XML
    End With

     For Each post In xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("dateStarts")
        r = r + 1:
        
        Cells(r, 1) = post.getElementsByTagName("d3p1:dateTime").Text
       
        MsgBox post.getElementsByTagName("d3p1:dateTime").Text
        
    Next post
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you need (to look up) a root element in the retrieved XML text. Perhaps: ArrayOfSHBForecast.

Comment: The http.responseXML.XML is empty. Maybe you can try to parse http.responseText.

Comment: I'd guess you need to add the namespace before trying to access the elements which use that namespace.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199739/vbscript-msxml-and-namespaces

Comment: On review - when called from VBA, that URL returns JSON, not XML.

Comment: Thanks for quick feedback everyone! Just two follow-up questions:  1) How can I tell that it is a JSON and not XML?  2) How would I amend the coding to adjust for JSON (or is there a good previous thread on this?)  Thanks!

Comment: 1)I just looked at the `responseText` property 2)This is the typical library used in VBA for parsing JSON: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON.  Previous posts on this topic: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+parse+json+site:stackoverflow.com